# Multi-target classification in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, targets

How to implement Multi-target classification in tensorflow? Say I have a list of features f1,f2,...,fn and i want to predict the class or a value of three targets t1,t2,and t3. So each target belongs to a single class only.

Comment: does this problem fall into the category of multitask learning problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're interested in [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression). In TensorFlow, the most important function for this is [tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2).

This [site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) gives a good idea how the softmax function makes it possible to classify a point in multiple categories.